# Tracing slow batch insert queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, batch-insert

I have a program that at some point performs thousands of inserts into a MySQL table. Those inserts are surrounded by a transaction. When I run the code on a dev machine using production data (copied prod. db), it takes a couple of minutes to complete. When I run it in production, it runs for over 30 minutes.

Both dev and prod servers run MySQL 5.1 (with a minor version diff, 5.1.64 vs 5.1.41 in prod). The server is a powerful machine with 12 cores, 16GB RAM, fast disks, etc (compared to my puny dev computer). The only difference is that the production machine is also a MySQL replication master. However, the specific schema that I write to isn't replicated.

I'm leaning towards placing the problem on `my.cnf` configuration values, but any other ideas will help. I've also noticed that although the specific schema isn't replicated, it also isn't ignored in the binlog (`binlog-ignore-db = <db-name>` in the `[mysqld]` section), so this is also something I'd like to look into.

What are other red flags I should pay attention to in configuration values to improve the speed of thousands-of-inserts scale transactions? Where else should I be looking to improve batch insert performance? thanks.

#### EDIT - the code that does this (very simplified)

in ruby, using `mysql2` adapter:

```
inserts = []

# a loop that generates INSERT statements

...
inserts << insert_stmt
...

# end loop

begin
  connection.query("BEGIN;")
  inserts.each { |q| connection.query(q) }
  connection.query("COMMIT;")
rescue
  connection.query("ROLLBACK;")
end
```

Comment: What else is the server doing while your import is happening? 'show processlist;' - also - are the tables indexed the same in both places?

Comment: I've run it many times and always the runtime is an order of magnitude longer, regardless of other processes (checked - nothing major is running). I've used `mysqldump` on the production db to run in dev mode when I tested the performance.

Comment: Are you using 'load data infile'?

Comment: Just `BEGIN; /* many INSERT statements */ ; COMMIT;` (via ruby's Mysql2 adapter, if that matters).